# Applying numpy random.choice to randomise categories with probabilities from pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Just trying to generate a new column in a dataframe, which takes the value 1 or 0 based on a probability located in other columns in the same row.

with dummy data: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [.1, .2, .3, .4], 'b': [.9, .8, .7, .6']})`

I'm hoping to add a third column c, which in the first row for instance would have a .1 probability of being 1, and a .9 of being 0. And so on.

**First attempt** was defining a function and using apply:

```
def randomiser(x):

    return np.random.choice([1,0], size=(1, 1), p=[df.loc[[x]]['a'], -df.loc[[x]]['b']])

df['probability'] = df.apply(lambda x: randomiser(x), axis=1)
```

However this would throw up an error about two many values being supplied to p, so I don't think it's iterating properly.

**Second** I tried a for loop:

```
for row in df.iterrows():

    row['probability'] = np.random.choice([1,0], size=(1, 1), p=[df.loc[[row]]['a'], -df.loc[[row]]['b']])
```

But this leads to a TypeError complaining that series objects are mutable.

**Finally** I tried pulling the relevant columns out into tuples or lists, but with similar results.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how `apply()` works you don't need to specify `df.loc[]` you must use `x` and the name of the column you wish get the values from. Try with the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [.1, .2, .3, .4], 'b': [.9, .8, .7, .6]})
def randomiser(x):

    return np.random.choice([1,0], size=(1, 1), p=[x['a'], x['b']])[0][0]
df['probability'] = df.apply(lambda x: randomiser(x), axis=1)
```

This outputs:

```
    a    b  probability
0  0.1  0.9            1
1  0.2  0.8            0
2  0.3  0.7            0
3  0.4  0.6            1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you solve the problem. I tried to modify your code a bit, but keep the original approach so you could learn what didn't work in the first time (:

Answer (score 0):

```
df["probability"] = [np.random.choice([1, 0], p=probs).item()
                     for probs in df[["a", "b"]].values]
```

With this list comprehension, we pass each row of `df` to `np.random.choice` as probabilities and choose from `[1, 0]` respectively (`.item` is there to grab the scalar from 1-entry array).

to get (for example)

```
     a    b  probability
0  0.1  0.9            0
1  0.2  0.8            0
2  0.3  0.7            0
3  0.4  0.6            1
```